# Show postgres group schema permissions

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psql, postgresql-10

I've performed the following on a postgres instance:

```
create group dev;
grant select on all tables in schema public to dev;
```

All I'm trying to do is query a view/table to find this grant. I've tried looking in views like `information_schema.table_privileges` but can't see it. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

P.S. this needs to be a view to query as I'm running it from a python script, not psql.

EDIT: PostgreSQL version 10.0

Answer (score 0):

```
-bash-4.2$ psql t -E
psql (9.3.14)
Type "help" for help.

t=# \dp+ schema_name.*
********* QUERY **********
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  c.relname as "Name",
  CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'm' THEN 'materialized view' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 'f' THEN 'foreign table' END as "Type",
  pg_catalog.array_to_string(c.relacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges",
  pg_catalog.array_to_string(ARRAY(
    SELECT attname || E':\n  ' || pg_catalog.array_to_string(attacl, E'\n  ')
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
    WHERE attrelid = c.oid AND NOT attisdropped AND attacl IS NOT NULL
  ), E'\n') AS "Column access privileges"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r', 'v', 'm', 'S', 'f')
  AND n.nspname ~ '^(schema_name)$'
ORDER BY 1, 2;
**************************
```

so you can use same logic for your query, eg to list privs for user `f` in schema `schema_name`:

```
with l as (select relname,unnest(relacl) from pg_class c join pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace where nspname = 'schema_name')
select * from l where unnest::text like 'f=%';
                       relname                       |    unnest
-----------------------------------------------------+--------------
 a_b                                                 | f=r/postgres
 b_c                                                 | f=r/postgres
```

Comment: Neither of these queries return anything for me. I'm looking to specifically show the grant `select on all tables in schema public`. Thanks for the `-E` hint though, that'll come in handy.